# MarkLogic Directory with backslash

Tags: marklogic

Currently several documents has been loaded into MarkLogic with wrong file separator "\" (backslash) as given below.

```
\TEST\fldr1\fldr2\fldr3\test.xml
\TEST\fldr1\fldr2\fldr3\test1.xml
\TEST\fldr1\fldr2\fldr3\test2.xml
```

When I try to perform,

```
cts:directory-query("\TEST\fldr1\fldr2\fldr3\", "1")
```

I am getting the below error.

```
Directory URI must end with "/"
```

Kindly let me know how to proceed on this issue.

Comment: How many of these files are there? Just those three? Is there a reason you can't just reinsert them with the correct character as path separator?

Comment: How did you load the files? You will want to use forward slash inside MarkLogic database. We could suggest how if you tell us how you loaded your files..

Comment: Unfortunately i am not aware how the docs were loaded. One million docs were loaded in such a state.

Answer (score 3):

With those URIs, MarkLogic isn't seeing directories, so the directory query isn't going to work even with escaping the backslashes. To do directory queries, you'll need to re-insert them. You can use this code to do so if there aren't too many:

```
(: TEST IN YOUR ENVIRONMENT BEFORE RUNNING! :)
for $uri in cts:uri-match('\*')
return (
  xdmp:document-insert(
    fn:replace($uri, '\\', '/'),
    fn:doc($uri),
    xdmp:document-get-permissions($uri),
    xdmp:document-get-collections($uri)
  ),
  xdmp:document-delete($uri)
)
```

Depending on how many documents you have, you might be able to do this in Query Console. If not, you could either increase the transaction time limit or take a look at [Corb2](https://github.com/marklogic/corb2).

Comment: Also, keep in mind that this inserts a new document. It does not remove the original version. You still need to do that (after, of course, confirming that your new document is there and happy)

Comment: Thanks for the query ! I have about a million docs hence will look into Corb2 as you suggested. We use, xdmp:document-delete($uri) at end of query here. Still the original version wont be deleted ?

Comment: The original version will be deleted, due to the xdmp:document-delete(). Related -- note that I'm assuming default quality and letting MarkLogic decide which forest to use. Adjust if needed. Test in a non-production environment.